# How does one define rigorous empathy?

Tags: meaning

How does one define rigorous empathy? I don't even know where to begin. What does it mean? On their own I know what each word means, but I know it's a lot deeper than that.

Comment: What if any evidence do you have that anyone else knows what "rigorous empathy" means? The two words are semantically orthogonal (if not actually *contradictory*). You might as well ask what [*sleep furiously*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1235072/) means. It's subjective, and thus Off Topic.

Comment: Context, please.

Comment: Where did you hear or see that expression?  Context would definitely help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need context for such term. Simply defining the meaning. What I came up with is this:

> We can define rigorous empathy as a thorough observation and the
>   desire to understand the trials and tribulations of a group of people. It is a a complex attempt at removing your own shoes and stepping into those you are trying to understand.